# can you select a tab programatically in tabbox of Shiny Dashboard?

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard

We can select tab in a `tabsetPanel` with `updateTabsetPanel`, or select a page in Dashboard with `updateTabItems`. However I didn't find a way to select tab by code in `tabBox`.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, `updateTabsetPanel` still works, I just need to use the tab title properly. For tabs we need `value` or `title` instead of `id` to identify it.

Comment: Do you think you could give a short example of the UI component and the corresponding updateTabsetPanel component? Thanks!